# nginx map : use value of a map in another map

Tags: nginx, webserver

As per nginx docs, it is possible to use variables as values in an nginx map. I want to do something like this:

```
map $http_host $subdomain {
   ~*.foo.com   foo-internal;
   ~*.bar.com   bar-internal;
}

map $app $server {
   app1    app1.$subdomain.example.com;
   app2    app2.$subdomain.example.com;
}

...
location ~ ^/(?<app>\w+)/(.*) {
    proxy_pass http://$server/$2$is_args$args;
}
```

So for a request to `foo.com/app1`, it can be proxied to `app1.foo-internal.example.com`, and a request to `bar.com/app2` would be proxied to `app2.bar-internal.example.com` (i.e. I need both maps to work in conjunction).

Hope my question is clear, let me know if not!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Unfortunately "The resulting value can be a string or another variable", so it can't be expression with variables :(

Comment: You mean it cannot be `app`.$subdomain` but can be `$subdomain` by itself? Oops :(

Comment: Yes. In your particular case you could use `proxy_pass http://$app.$subdomain.example.com/...`

Comment: Ah interesting - let me try this!